# Generic Enum in a Collection or vararg parameter

Tags: java, generics, enums

I'm trying to create a collection of `enum` classes so that I can iterate through the collection and then iterate through the enum values by calling `enumClass.getEnumConstants()`.

Given the following:

```
public interface MyEnumType {
   String getSubtype ();
}

public enum MyEnumTypeA implements MyEnumType {
   A_1,
   A_2;
   public String getSubtype () { return "A"; }
}

public enum MyEnumTypeB implements MyEnumType {
   B_1,
   B_2;
   public String getSubtype () { return "B"; }
}
```

I've tried using varargs:

```
private <T extends Enum<T> & MyEnumType> void handleTypes (
   Class<? extends T>... enumTypes )
{
   for( Class<? extends T> enumType : enumTypes )
      for( T value : enumType.getEnumConstants() )
         handleValue( value );
}

private void doStuff () {
   // error here
   handleTypes( MyEnumTypeA.class, MyEnumTypeB.class );
}
```

...but using wild-card generics in varargs produces a compilation error whenever I try to call the function

I've also tried building a `List`:

```
public class MyMainClass
{
   private static Collection<Class<Enum<? extends MyEnumType>>> ALL_TYPES
      = Lists.newArrayList();
   {
      // error here
      ALL_TYPES.add( MyEnumTypeA.class );
      ALL_TYPES.add( MyEnumTypeB.class );
   }
}
```

...but this too fails to compile when I try to `add` to the list.

The following works but requires a cast (no compilation errors or warnings if I passed in `Object.class`):

```
private void runNoMatchTests ( Class... enumTypes ) {
   for( Class enumType : enumTypes ) {
      for( MyEnumType value : ( (Class<MyEnumType>)enumType ).getEnumConstants() ) {
         handleValue( value );
      }
   }
}
```

How can this be done without using a cast? Can it be done without using a cast?

Comment: Java doesn't know ahead of time that any subtype of `MyEnumType` is actually an enum.

Comment: What is `handleValue`? Where are you getting the compilation error?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `handleValue` is just some random function that handles a `MyEnumType` object, it could be as simple as `System.out.println(value.getSubtype());`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure why this is the case, but your first attempt can compile if you change `<T extends Enum<T> & MyEnumType>` to `<T extends Enum<?> & MyEnumType>` as shown below:

```
private <T extends Enum<?> & MyEnumType> void handleTypes(Class<? extends T>... enumTypes) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Indeed, that does work! It gives me a useless warning about generics in varargs, but also gives a compilation error if I try to pass in `Object.class`. Thank you! If anybody could explain why, that would be appreciated also.